# Clamav can only open log file in specific directory

Tags: 14.04, clamav

When running

```
sudo freshclam -l /var/log/company/clamav/freshclam.log
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: Can't open /var/log/company/clamav/freshclam.log in append mode (check permissions!).
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/company/clamav/freshclam.log).
```

Permissions on `/var/log` and `/var/log/company` and `/var/log/company/clamav` are all set at 777  and I've tried `chown` to make the directories owned alternatively by `root:root`, `clamav:clamav`, and my personal user.  I get the same error when I try to store at `/var/log/freshclam.log`.  In each case I've tried both running the command when `freshclam.log` doesn't exist and with a pre-created file with 777 perms.  I can't see how the problem is with permissions when I've created such a universally permissive set of folders.  Permissions are so high I don't even want to know what kind of lewd parties my files are having in there

The frustrating bit is that it magically works when I set the log to store in the default dir, at `/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log`.  The permissions on that folder are no different from the other directories I've tried.

Is this simply a bug in `freshclam`?  The `clamscan` command properly saves logs anywhere I want, but `freshclam` just doesn't even run if I try to log ANYWHERE except the default location.

Is it such a huge difference to have the log stored one directory up? A non-trivial detail for my log aggregation setup, but mostly I hate being defeated like this!

EDIT:
I've verified that there is no other clamav process running. There is no other process trying to access the same logfile.

Comment: Had the same issue as you, except for the database directory, and on macOS using homebrew. With the folder at `/Users/daniel/Library/Homebrew/var/lib/clamav`, I'd get `ERROR: Can't open /Users/daniel/Library/Homebrew/var/lib/clamav in append mode (check permissions!).`, even with permissions set to crazy like you, on all the folders leading up to `clamav`. Placing it in `/Users/daniel/clamav`, it runs without complaining. Something's off (Interestingly, `freshclam` would not complain)

Comment: Doubly-weird: After `clamd` had run, it had placed a file (not a folder)  at `/Users/daniel/Library/Homebrew/var/lib/clamav`. Updating the conf to try to read that, it would error out with `LibClamAV Warning: cli_load: unknown extension - skipping /Users/daniel/Library/Homebrew/var/lib/clamav` `LibClamAV Error: cl_statdbdir(): Can't open directory /Users/daniel/Library/Homebrew/var/lib/clamav` `Tue Nov 27 08:54:42 2018 -> !Can't open file or directory` So weird